# DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll Not Working on Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: openxml

In my C# asp.net web application, used DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Dll to work with Excel file generation, it is working in one application server, but failed in another server, what would be the reason for it. How to check it?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In other system, excel created. But in that machine no excel created and in the event viewer also no error details. The applications not showing any error.

Comment: Include all the referenced DLL into EXE path. I m also faced same problem by excluding one of the DLL(windowsbase.dll). Try and let me know